# Usage and limitations of custom Eloquent query bindings with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Let's say the query looks like this:

```
$query = 'select * from some_table LIMIT :limit'
```

My db->selects are the following:

a) `$orders = $db->select($db->raw($query), array("limit" => '0,10'));`

b) `$orders = $db->select($db->raw($query), array("limit" => '10'));`

a) doesn't work, but b) does. Why?

Also this doesn't work:

```
$query2 = 'select :col from some_table LIMIT :limit';
$orders = $db->select($db->raw($query2), array("col" => "some_col","limit" => '10'));
```

Am I using it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to realize that prepared statements are not just formatted strings. The idea of prepared statements is that syntax and arguments are sent separately, so you can safely send user data without risking mysql injection. In query a) you are putting syntax in the parameter. The same can be said about the columns. Column names are part of the syntax.

Comment: so the bindings are only to be used with prepared statements?

Comment: Bindings can only be used in prepared statements. If you want to modify the column you can do 'select '.$colName.' from some_table'

Comment: Using bindings is only useful when the data comes from the user. If you want to insert his name in the database, you can use 'insert into users (name) values (:name)'. This way you don't have to worry about escaping quotes in his input.